# Possibility to run desktop application in a machine that doesn't contain a JVM

Tags: java, jvm

I am going to create a Desktop application in Java. I don't know whether user having JAVA VIRTUAL MACHINE or not.

My questions are:

1. I  want to know whether its possible to run Java application in a machine that doesn't contains JVM.
2. If its possible, I want to know whether this case is possible, I will created a application say MyApps, I will to convert this as .exe file and if user clicks MyApps.exe it should run my Java application and install JVM and run in that machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution for running my Java application without Java Virtual Machine, by bundling JRE in the exe file. I did this by using the following link.

It's really working awesome.

[JAVA without JVM using Launch4J](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://www.eteks.com/tips/tipCreationExe.html&act=url)

If we maintain the Directory Path as given we can get .exe with JRE bundled that will run without JVM.

Answer (score 3):

Use webstart, and to install java automatically, see the great comment of Andrew Thompson.

- Then the user is free to use Solaris, Mac or Linux if he likes.
- and updates for the JVM will be shipped to him. You don't need to rollout a new update for every bugfix in the JVM or Java-libs.

Comment: If there is no `javaws` to process the `*.jnlp`files, would WebStart run?

Comment: Oh, yes, I'm sorry, the answer is wrong. :) I will correct it.

Comment: @Thomas Use [deployJava.js](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) to help ensure there **is** a suitable minimum version of the JRE & [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS has been co-bundled with the JRE since around Java 1.4.2.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I know that javaws is bundled, but I wasn't aware of `deployJava.js`. Thanks for that hint (+1) - Edit: one question though: It seems like deployJava.js actually tries to run an applet (`runApplet(...)` is called), so would it run if there is no support for Java in the browser?

Comment: @Thomas: I'm sorry, but reading the page, linked by Andrew, doesn't make me sure, and I can't uninstall Java, just to see whether it works. Maybe you can test it in a VM?

Comment: Well, it should be testable in VM. Unfortunately I don't have a system without Java right now (and no VM), but you could try Virtual Box, setup a small system and test.

Comment: @Thomas Re. deployJava.js "..would it run if there is no support for Java in the browser?"  Yes.  All it requires is that **JavaScript** is enabled, and it is becoming hard to navigate the web these days, without JS.  Note 1) it does not *guarantee* success, but should give the user meaningful feedback if the installation cannot be completed successfully.  Note 2) the script is for both writing applet elements (running an applet) as well as writing a launch button for JWS apps.

Comment: @Andrew What I mean is: Would the applet started by that JavaScript run if the browser had no Java support at all? Or does `runApplet(...)` actually run a JavaScript 'applet' and the name is just misleading?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can run a Java application on a machine which does not have a JVM, provided you install the version of Java you need first.
2. You can create an application which will install java as required and then run your application.  However you cannot write this in Java (unless you have a JVM installed already)

This is not completely pointless as many system have some version of Java but may not have the version you need.

Comment: *You can run a Java application on a machine which does not have a JVM, provided you install the version of Java you need first.* ... That would install the JVM surely?

Comment: "You can create an application which will install java as required and then run your application. However you cannot write this in Java (unless you have a JVM installed already)" - Writing this in Java would really be fun ;)

Comment: Hi peter i facing one problem regarding the installer please guide me check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407178/problem-in-bundling-jre-in-jsmooth-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you need a JVM to run the Java bytecode. The only solution would be to transform the bytecode into a different executable format.